# Catch DllNotFoundException from P/Invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, dllimport, dllnotfoundexception

**Found post with a solution**: [How do I handle a failed DllImport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970017/how-do-i-handle-a-failed-dllimport)

I'm writing an app that checks the OS version to do different things depending on whether the host is using a Vista-series or NT-series version of Windows. If Vista-series, it loads some DLLs (using DllImport), but doesn't use these otherwise. The problem is, using DllImport to load them will cause a DllNotFoundException at runtime if used on older versions of Windows that don't have those DLLs.

How can I catch / prevent / ignore the DllNotFoundExceptions? Trying to set the exception to "Handled" in my unhandled exception event does not allow the app to continue.

Comment: Is the exception being thrown at the call-site or when the program loads (but before you actually try to call those functions)?

Comment: Catching exceptions is suboptimal, as one should avoid having exceptions being part of the normal application flow. In your case, on a specific platform, each call would first throw an exception, which I'd avoid if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should be able to go the "traditional" way with the win32 LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress/FreeLibrary and a delegate (just as you do it with callback functions).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d186xcf0.aspx might be a starting point...

This should get you started:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling=true, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procName);
```

Then you declare a delegate with the correct signature of the export to be called, and use  [Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getdelegateforfunctionpointer.aspx) to create it from a function pointer you got back from [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

As an option you could write some sort of decorator component in C++/CLI which would forward all calls to windows dlls using LoadLibrary or static linking and handle manually any absences of those dlls.